# COUNTIF Formula not returning expected values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I'm currently attempting to create a formula for my spreadsheet that will calculate the total completion percentage of the form by counting all "Pass" and/or "Fail" results found within columns B through H.

```
=COUNTIFS(B3:H100,I89,B3:H100,I95)
```

This is what I have currently, but no matter how many cells are listed as Pass or Fail, the total stays at 0.
[image: Design 1]

```
=COUNTIF(B78:H100,I89)
```

This is the formula I used to calculate the percentage of cells that return with a "Pass" (Pass being the data listed in cell I89) and it works in this instance.
[image: Design 2]

With this in mind, what would be the best solution to my situation?

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure this is happening because you're asking it to count two separate values from the same range and it's saying "What do you want from me?!"

Comment: Perhaps, but "Pass" and "Fail" aren't the only values that are found in the cells. "Not Started" and "In Progress" will both be values listed in the cells; however, I don't want these values being considered in the completion percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you probably want to do something like this:

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:C3,I1),COUNTIFS(A1:C3,I2))`

Since it seems you want the sum of two `COUNTIFS`, however when you try and specify two values to count in the same range it freaks out and gives you a value of 0.

To get the percentage, just divide by the total number of values:

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:C3,A1),COUNTIFS(A1:C3,C1))/COUNTA(A1:C3)`

Personally, I probably would have worked this out like so:

```
Number of PASS results (in F1):        =COUNTIF(A1:C3,E1)
Number of FAIL results (in F2):        =COUNTIF(A1:C3,E2)
Number of NOT STARTED results (in F3): =COUNTIF(A1:C3,E3)
COMPLETION percentage:                 =SUM(F1:F2)/SUM(F1:F3)
```

[image: Example Table]
[image: Example Table w/ formulas]

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for the assistance!!

Answer (score 0):

COUNTIFS is `AND` not `OR`.  So it is literally looking for cells that are both equal to `Pass` and `Fail` at the same time in the same cell, which is not possible.

To do `OR` you need to either do two separate COUNTIFs and add them together:

```
=COUNTIF(B78:H100,I89)+COUNTIF(B78:H100,I95)
```

Or use an array and wrap in sumproduct:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(B78:H100,IF({1,0},I89,I95)))
```

But since you already have the two cells with their own COUNTIF(), why not just add the two cells together:

```
=I90 + I96
```